# How to download page with actual chrome session by java

Tags: java, google-chrome, html

I would like to ask how to download webpage with actual session using java program. I would like to download for eg. a facebook page that I am currently loged on google-chrome. Is it possible to use chrome session?

Comment: Nope, that would be a security flaw.

Comment: ok, so do you know to login into a webpage using java?

Comment: It really depends on the page.. Basically you would have to POST a HTTP request to a specific URL with specific parameters. **But in your case** I think using Facebook API could be worthy (or even a Java API for Facebook like http://facebook4j.org/en/index.html).

Comment: Oh, facebook was just an examle. I would like to login into this page:
http://www.4clubbers.com.pl/login.php?do=login